# How do you create an array of the coordinates inside of a cube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm experimenting with some matplotlib_3d plots, and as such I'm starting to delve into numpy too.

I want to create a cube on a 3d plot, within certain bounds. This requires an array of coordinates, each of length 3.
Eg. for a cube of side length 3, the result would be a 2d array of length 27, comprised of tuples:

```
[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 0] # first "layer" on the z axis
[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1] # second "layer" on the z axis
[0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2] # thrid "layer" on the z axis
```

I understand the use of `numpy.meshgrid`to generate the coordinate like arrays when given a series of ranges, however trying to "zip" those arrays together into the format described above (order is irrelevant), I get lost completely. So far, I have tried the following:

```
x, y, z= np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 3), np.arange(0, 3), np.arange(0, 3))
x >> [[[0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]]
y >> [[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]]]
z >> [[[0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]]

 [[0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]]

 [[0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]
  [0 1 2]]]
```

Now I try to "zip" them together using `numpy.dstack([x, y, z])`, the result is:

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2]
  [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 2]
  [2 2 2 0 0 0 0 1 2]]

 [[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 2]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2]
  [2 2 2 1 1 1 0 1 2]]

 [[0 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 2]
  [1 1 1 2 2 2 0 1 2]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 2]]]
```

I understand that in `reshape`might be of use here as it is in other cases, but I don't know how to apply it to this case.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to create the array mentioned at the start of the post? More examples and short explanations would be much appreciated, thanks and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, just need to flatten the coordinates:

```
x, y, z= np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 3), np.arange(0, 3), np.arange(0, 3))
np.stack([x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten()], axis = -1)
```

Comment: That works - thanks!
Can you elaborate as to why you chose to use `flatten` over `ravel`? And what does the `axis = -1` do?